# Writing a valid multi-dimensional array into JSON

Tags: json

I'm trying to return a JSON string from an AJAX call to my database but I'm having a bit of trouble...  I can't seem to get the notation of my JSON correct as it keeps evaluating to a single dimension array and chopping off a bunch...

Here's an example of what I have so far (truncated for brevity's sake):

```
[{
    "Credit",
    "Accounting, see also Business",
    "BA 051",
    "4",
    "Accounting Procedures 1"
  },
  {
    "Credit",
    "Accounting, see also Business",
    "BA 052",
    "4",
    "Accounting Procedures 2"
  }...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

`[` is array which requires `value`s.

`{` is associative array or object which requires `"name":value` pairs.